# Formatting Chart Legends Using With (Syntax)

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a macro which adds and removes (filterseries) set data series of a chart (in its own sheet) by looping through checkboxes in a separate sheet.  When I add and remove them, I want to cycle the legend off then back on so that it resizes itself automatically.

I think this is just a syntax error of how I'm using the with statement.

I have a separate macro which does this for a different purpose, but it loops through chart-sheets and treats them as variables and, for some reason, it works there.

```
Sub ISurfSeries1Checklist()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    For i = 1 To 56
        If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Range").Cells(3 + i, 12).Value = True Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Charts("I. Surf (1)").FullSeriesCollection(i).IsFiltered = False

        Else 'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Range").Cells(3 + i, 12) = False Then

        ActiveWorkbook.Charts("I. Surf (1)").FullSeriesCollection(i).IsFiltered = True

        End If
    Next i

    For c = 51 To 56 'ActiveWorkbook.Charts("I. Surf (1)").FullSeriesCollection.Count

    ActiveWorkbook.Charts("I. Surf (1)").FullSeriesCollection(c).Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
    ActiveWorkbook.Charts("I. Surf (1)").FullSeriesCollection(c).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ActiveWorkbook.Charts("I. Surf (1)").FullSeriesCollection(c).Format.Line.Transparency = 0

    Next c

    ActiveWorkbook.Charts("I. Surf (1)").HasLegend = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Charts("I. Surf (1)").HasLegend = True

    '***Below is where it stops working.***
    With ActiveWorkbook.Charts("I.Surf (1)").Legend
        .Font.Size = 8
        .Border.Weight = xlHairline
        .Border.Color = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Left = Cht_Sht.PlotArea.InsideLeft - Cht_Sht.Axes(xlValue).Format.Line.Weight
        .Top = Cht_Sht.PlotArea.InsideTop
   End With
```

Comment: What is the error message you get and in which line exactly do you get the error?

Comment: Hi.  The message is "Runtime Error '9'.  Subscript out of range" and it happens on the "With" line.

Answer (score 0):

> *Runtime Error '9'. Subscript out of range*
>   on the `With` statement: `With ActiveWorkbook.Charts("I.Surf (1)").Legend`

That means a chart named `"I.Surf (1)"` does not exist you are probably missing the space between the dot and `Surf`. It should be `"I. Surf (1)"`.

I recommend to reference the chart by a variable so you only have to use its name once. Coding rule number 1: *Don't repeat yourself.*

```
Dim ActChart As Chart
Set ActChart = ActiveWorkbook.Charts("I. Surf (1)")
```

This prevents typos and if you have to change it you only need to change it in one position:

```
Sub ISurfSeries1Checklist()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim ActChart As Chart
    Set ActChart = ActiveWorkbook.Charts("I. Surf (1)")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 56
        'Note that you can shorten this to:
        ActChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).IsFiltered = Not (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Range").Cells(3 + i, 12).Value = True)
    Next i

    Dim c As Long
    For c = 51 To 56 'ActiveWorkbook.Charts("I. Surf (1)").FullSeriesCollection.Count
        With ActChart.FullSeriesCollection(c).Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
    Next c

    ActChart.HasLegend = False
    ActChart.HasLegend = True

    With ActChart.Legend
        .Font.Size = 8
        .Border.Weight = xlHairline
        .Border.Color = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Left = Cht_Sht.PlotArea.InsideLeft - Cht_Sht.Axes(xlValue).Format.Line.Weight
        .Top = Cht_Sht.PlotArea.InsideTop
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Peh,  

Thanks very much.  I will try this out.  However, I should also admit this is is directly the product of breaking rule No. 1 under the doolish assumption that I wont have to repeat it in the other name-specific charts.